# Publishing photo to Facebook via Graph API: OAuthException: (#100) param tags must be an array

Tags: arrays, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, photos

I'm attempting to upload a photo to Facebook via the Graph API on a test user account for my app. With just the `url, link, name` parameters present, the upload works fine returning a valid photo id.

**However, if I use the additional `tags` parameter, I end up with the following error returned:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) param tags must be an array.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I've tried to provide the value for `tags` in almost every possible way I can think of, as I know the Graph API isn't straightforward (even the parameter `url` which is used to upload a photo from a URL isn't listed under the `photo` Graph API method);

**A single user id**

`tags=100003919104407`

**Multiple CS'd user ids**

`tags=100003919104407,100003919104408,100003919104409`

**Array with ids not as integers**

`tags=[100003919104407, 100003919104404,100003919104405]`

**Array with ids as strings**

`tags=["100003919104407", "100003919104404","100003919104405"]`

**Array containing objects, as per the Facebook Graph API documentation**

`tags=[{"id":"100003919104407"},{"id":"100003919104404"},{"id":"100003919104405"}]`

If someone could tell me the right format/another parameter through which to pass user ids in order to have them tagged in a photo, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Guys you can try this [solution][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742120/unable-to-upload-and-tag-photo-on-facebook-application-php/10764438#10764438

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

It should be in this format

```
[{"to":"100003919104407","x":0,"y":0},  
{"to":"100003919104408","x":10,"y":10},  
{"to":"100003919104409","x":20,"y":20}]
```

or

```
[{"tag_uid":"100003919104407","x":0,"y":0},
{"tag_uid":"100003919104408","x":10,"y":10},
{"tag_uid":"100003919104409","x":20,"y":20}]
```

Comment: The second seems to work, (returns `true`) but when I check the photo object for a `tags` connection, none exist.

Comment: Try 'id' instead of tag_uid. earlier I had used tag_uid. but doc specifying id somewhere and to somewhere. so you have to try that too.

Comment: Did u check the comment u got for question. It seems  u can only tag to existing photo. Please try that.

Comment: Tried id as specified by doc, didn't work either (that was my original point of call). I do know however, that despite the tags not being shown with a `GET` request to `http://graph.facebook.com/<[photo_id]>`, the subject of the tag did have the photo show up in "Photos of me". I'm  wondering if maybe the fact that these were test accounts and the Graph API Explorer was being used could have an effect?

Comment: Ah, that was the issue. **You cannot tag a photo using test user accounts**. Presumably this is because tagging needs to take place on a real/live graph object, and as test user accounts do not create real/live objects on the graph, they're rendered ineligible for tagging and such.

Comment: Gald to hear that you have fixed it by own. I wasn't here yesterday. So couldn't able to help you much. Yes I agree with you about the presumption.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get your information from? Have you check the [tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags) section?

> Create
>
> You can create a tag on the photo by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   the tags connection, PHOTO_ID/tags.
>
> Note: This feature is intended to help users tag their friends in real
>   photos. You should not use this feature to encourage users to tag
>   their friends if their friends are not actually in that photo, or to
>   tag friends in composite photos. If your app is found to be
>   encouraging this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.
>
> You can specify which user to tag using two methods: in the URL path
>   as PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID, or in a URL parameter as
>   PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID. To add several tags at once, you can specify
>   a tags property which contains an array of tags like so
>   PHOTO_ID/tags?tags=[{"id":"1234"}, {"id":"12345"}]. Currently, you
>   cannot tag a Page in a photo using this API.

There's also an [example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/).

Answer (score 1):

the X and Y value of array need to be %, not in pixels

**Example 1 (wrong)**

img:(640,480) xy:(320,240)
[{tag_uid:user_id,x:320,y:240}] <- wrong, because 320 > 100%

**Example 2 (right)**
img:(640,480) xy:(320,240) px:(320,240) < %

[{tag_uid:user_id,x:50,y:50}] <- right, because 50 < 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a list to the required parameter and it throws "param tags must be an array" error, please convert the list to str and pass it. It will work. You are welcome.